# Drone Deployment Platform for Neural Networks

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, robotics

Good day everyone,

I would just like to ask if anyone part of a lab or company doing research on aerial robotics has any suggestions of a good platform for deploying computer vision algorithms for aerial robots?

Currently our lab has a set of DJI Matrice drones but are too heavy for our liking. We really wanted to use the Skydio R2 drone for out future research projects but found out later that the SDK does not allow access for implementing our own Deep Learning or Reinforcement Learning networks (only allows the user to code their own preset movements in python). We also took a look at the Parrot AR drones but found that they were discontinued and do not have the computing power that the Skydio has although as an alternative, it does have the capability to stream the video feed to an external computer for online processing instead of on-board.

I suggested that we stick with the DJI Matrice and just use an Nvidia Jetson for deployment but I am still curious to know if anyone knows of other available platforms. Does anyone know of a more compact platform available for research purposes?

Thank you :)